# Определить является ли слово палиндромом. Функция и цикл. Python

Tags: python, функции, циклы

Нужно определить является ли слово палиндромом. Обязательно через функцию, и если я понял правильно внутри функции должен быть цикл. Вот пример как должен выглядеть результат:

Enter a word: python

not a palindrome

Enter a word: java

not a palindrome

Enter a palindrome: auto

not a palindrome

Enter a palindrome: madam

madam is palindrome!

Вот мой вариант кода:

```
s=input("enter a word: ")
reverse=s[::-1]
def palindrom(s):
    while True:
        if s[::1]==reverse:
            print(s,"is palindrome ")
            break
        if s!=reverse:
            print(s,"not a palindrome !")
            continue 
            
print(palindrom(s))
```

Спасибо

Comment: Ну а как можно понять, что слово палиндром? Сравнить первый символ с последним, потом второй с предпоследним и так далее. Осталось записать это в цикле.

Comment: и в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Зачем вам вечный цикл, внутри которого ничего не изменяется? Тогда запрос ввода должен быть внутри цикла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю авторы задания подразумевали немного другое. Попытаюсь представить своё виденье "верного" решения

```py
def pcheck(word: str): #задаём тип данных входного параметра, так что бы можно было передать аргумент только в формате строки
    iters = len(word)//2 #получаем количество итераций, необходимых для проверки (надо обойти все буквы кроме центральной)
    for i in range(iters): #проходим слово в цикле
        if word[i] != word[-i - 1]: #проверяем на сходство зеркальную букву слова
            return False #возращаем False, тем самым сообщая что слово не является палиндромом (оператор return при этом завершает выполнение функции)
    return True #в данном случае мы дошли до конца функции и точно знаем, что все зеркальные буквы совпадают
```

Как вы видите, функция просто обходит слово с двух сторон, проверяя совпадения букв с правого и левого края. Также надо заметить, что функция чувствительна к регистру. Данную "оплошность" можно устранить, применив к строке функцию `lower()`(она переведёт всю строку в нижний регистр).

Теперь сделаем проверку на палиндром в цикле

```py
while True:
    word = input('Enter a word: ') #получаем слово на ввод
    print(f'{word} is palindrome' if pcheck() else 'not a palindrome') #выводим результат
```

Итоговый код:

```py
def pcheck(word: str): #задаём тип данных входного параметра, так что бы можно было передать аргумент только в формате строки
    iters = len(word)//2 #получаем количество итераций, необходимых для проверки (надо обойти все буквы кроме центральной)
    for i in range(iters): #проходим слово в цикле
        if word[i] != word[-i - 1]: #проверяем на сходство зеркальную букву слова
            return False #возращаем False, тем самым сообщая что слово не является палиндромом (оператор return при этом завершает выполнение функции)
    return True #в данном случае мы дошли до конца функции и точно знаем, что все зеркальные буквы совпадают

while True:
    word = input('Enter a word: ') #получаем слово на ввод
    print(f'{word} is palindrome' if pcheck() else 'not a palindrome') #выводим результат
```

Answer (score 10):

Самый простой и красивый вариант:

```
def palindrome(s):
    return s[::-1] == s

while True:
    s = input("Enter a palindrome: ")
    print(f"{s} is palindrome!" if palindrome(s) else "not a palindrome")
```

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю просто перевернуть строку

```
string_to_check = input("Enter a string")

if string_to_check == string_to_check[::-1]:
    print("This is a palindrome")
else:
    print("This is not a palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

как вариант логики: в цикле перебираете буквы слова до середины длины (i < length / 2), сравниваете букву word[i] и word[word.length - i - 1]. если на каком-либо этапе буквы не равны - возращаете false из функции. если цикл закончился - true